# pass value of textfield to another textfield on next page

Tags: php, html, session

I have table displayed on a page. Table as:

id name  birthdate school

1  ABCD  XX-XX-XX   XYZ      'edit icon'

2  PQRS  XX-XX-XX   LMN      'edit icon'

If I click on edit icon I want to pass name ABCD on next page. Anybody have idea how to do it? I tried by using `session()` but it doesnt pass value.

Thanks in advance.

code to display table:

```
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td height='30'><a href='next.php?name=".$info['name']."'><img src='image/edit-icon.png'></a>" . $info['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td height='30' id='key'>" . $info['name'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<td height='30'>" . $data['date'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<td height='30'>" . $info['school'] . "</td></tr> ";
```

I want pass name on next page to edit records.

Comment: What you have tried..??

Comment: Show the code you have tried so far... you will not get a real answer showing that little effort, I'm afraid.

Comment: See my answer it will help you further and for long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to put Id for each individual edit and link them as

```
nextpage.php?id=$this_id
```

and in next page get the id as

```
$this_id = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

Then put a query for the records that are having id as $this_id like

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = ".$this_id);
```

then you will get all the data that you have selected easily like

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $data['name'];?>">
```

Comment: You can get name only passing through url and GET it in next page but you need to learn it further....Hope it helps for you such a long

Comment: url i got after using this: id = 

nothing is pass to url

Comment: Your $info array will have id for that record ...that you given as primary key for each entry....that you need to pass through url

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just store ABCD in one variable and pass it in URL

```
nextpage.php?name=ABCD
```

**nextpage.php**

get that value via

```
$_REQUEST['name'];

OR

$_GET['name'];
```

Comment: I got error :  Function name must be a string
and its not only ABCD. table contains lots other names

Comment: so he needs to pass id. and then fetch records via `id`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the id of the row that present in the db table with the URL use in edit icon.
and fetch the data on next page on the basis of that id.
And you can set the data in text fields also.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and simplest way to do this is to pass it with $_GET to the other script.

The edit icon should get an `onclick="window.open('newpage.php?name=ABCD');"` and you can access it on newpage.php with `$_GET['name']`

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the table, be sure to put the name in the link.

```
<a href="edit.php?name=ABCD"><img src="..." /> </a>
```

Then, in edit.php you can retrieve the name calling

$_REQUEST['name'];